# Can DirectX9 be used without HWND handle?

Tags: c++, directx, directx9

I found an excellent code here that does almost everything I need: running an HLSL shader on memory texture to process video frames into another texture buffer without displaying it.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207642/Video-Shadering-with-Direct-D?msg=5092502#xx5092502xx

My question is: can DirectX9 be used to work purely with in-memory data without display and without specifying a HWND handle? What needs to change in the code if not giving it a HWND?

The code I'm writing is a DLL that has no graphical interface.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that DirectX CreateDevice will simply fail without a HWND. However, a HWND can easily be created with this:

```
HWND dummyHWND = CreateWindowA("STATIC", "dummy", NULL, 0, 0, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```